# geom_smooth, stat_smooth confidence interval not working?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have these data:

```
structure(list(Run = c("A013", "A015", "A023", "A024", "A031", 
"A032", "A035", "A040", "A045", "A046", "A049", "A013", "A015", 
"A023", "A024", "A031", "A032", "A035", "A040", "A045", "A046", 
"A013", "A015", "A023", "A024", "A031", "A032", "A035", "A040", 
"A013", "A015", "A023", "A024", "A031", "A032", "A035", "A040", 
"A013", "A015", "A023", "A024", "A031", "A032", "A013", "A015", 
"A023", "A024", "A013", "A015", "A023", "A024"), Step = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L), .Label = c("1", "e", "k", "2", "q", "b", "m"), class = "factor"), 
    Weight = c(87.4064, 79.5822, 117.0674, 102.6384, 134.0752, 
    111.2398, 107.8464, 111.2576, 104.2428, 110.2848, 28.7292, 
    41.65656, 73.9356, 84.18504, 89.4845, 71.55106, 86.04072, 
    76.27296, 92.8749, 85.203, 91.92112, 39.5009258, 58.6035081, 
    75.13589946, 83.43157667, 88.8993795, 68.85183559, 64.77081269, 
    77.56733054, 32.5025, 51.45329, 66.29101, 73.79125, 79.95483, 
    60.9573, 58.34856, 68.83193, 29.65289, 40.74267, 56.97243, 
    61.48708, 70.24226, 54.79253, 22.8231064, 38.9966088, 55.2736576, 
    62.6077916, 20.7458048, 38.306526, 54.7937568, 61.1417148
    )), .Names = c("Run", "Step", "Weight"), row.names = c(NA, 
-51L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to get a nice looking geom_smooth() with 0.99 confidence using

```
require(ggplot2)
require(directlabels)
g1 <- ggplot(m1,
             aes(x=Step,y=Weight,label=Run,group=Run,color=Run)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line()
g2 <- g1 +  geom_dl(method="first.bumpup")
g2 + geom_smooth(aes(group=1),level=0.99)
```

Here are my problems:

1. The error ribbon doesn't look like 99% confidence, lots of points in the chart are outside it.
2. When I expand the data set, the error ribbon collapses to very narrow where the majority of the points are outside it.

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks,

Edit: here's what I see when I run this:
[image: Narrow ribbon]
When I look at a bigger data set, the ribbon gets even narrower, almost being on top of the smooth line.

Comment: This is the confidence interval of the _mean_, you're talking about. I think what you're after is prediction interval. Shameless self promotion ahead: http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7024

Comment: You are right. I was confusing what the confidence interval means in this case. I will explore your option.

Comment: Too bad you have not added an example here I would mark it as correct. Also it would be nice to derive an equation I could apply to a specific point, say A046 at step e and it could predict what the weight will be at the last step, step m.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confidence intervals and prediction intervals are two different beasts. The former is about the mean of your data (fitted values), while the latter is where future observations will lie.

This is my code from [RPubs repository](http://rpubs.com/RomanL/7024).

```
set.seed(357)
library(ggplot2) # for ggplot()
library(gridExtra) 

x <- rnorm(20)
y <- x * rnorm(20, mean = 3, sd = 1)
xy <- data.frame(x, y)

mdl <- lm(y ~ x, data = xy)

# Predict these data for...
predx <- data.frame(x = seq(from = -2, to = 3, by = 0.1))

# ... confidence interval
conf.int <- cbind(predx, predict(mdl, newdata = predx, interval = "confidence", level = 0.95))

# ... prediction interval
pred.int <- cbind(predx, predict(mdl, newdata = predx, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95))
man <- predict(mdl, newdata = predx, se = TRUE)

# Manual calculation of confidence interval, tolerance of 0.95 (1.96).
lvl <- qt(1-(1 - 0.95)/2, mdl$df.residual) # Thank you, @Roland (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/10581408#10581408)
conf.int.man <- cbind(predx, fit = man$fit, lwr = man$fit - lvl * man$se.fit, upr = man$fit + lvl * man$se.fit)

g.conf <- ggplot(conf.int, aes(x = x, y = fit)) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Confidence interval of estimated parameters from predict()") +
  geom_point(data = xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(data = conf.int, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), stat = "identity") 

g.pred <- ggplot(pred.int, aes(x = x, y = fit)) +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Prediction interval for future observations from predict()") +
  geom_point(data = xy, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(data = pred.int, aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr), stat = "identity")

grid.arrange(g.conf, g.pred, ncol = 2)
```

[image]